# Altium 19 stack manager and Gerber file setup

Tags: pcb, power-electronics, altium, pcb-layers, gerber

I have installed Altium Designer 19 recently but I have two problems with this version:

First of all, when I open the layer stack manager I can not see "save and load and advance" at bottom. I don't know how to fix this issue!

Second, when I am in Gerber setup menu I can not see this option "board outline".

[image]

[image]

Sorry if my questions look very weird, but I don't have as much experience with Altium Designer as most of you guys.

Comment: Not sure if it is the "best way" to do it, but I usually draw the board outline on a separate mechanical layer and then add this layer to all the plots.

Answer (score 2):

Altium 19 has moved things around.

With the Stackup manager window being active, if you click File, you will see "Save Template as" and "Load Template". This is the equivalent of what you are looking for.

As for the board outline, I use a mechanical layer for the board outline and export it along with the rest of the gerber files and in a document state what the different layers are, including the mechanical layer being the board outline.

Answer (score 2):

Like @RemcoVink mentions, there is no dedicated board outline layer in Altium.  You can pick any mechanical layer, and draw the board outline on that.  You then must inform the board house which Gerber layer contains the board outline (usually in a readme.txt file and CAM notes on another mechanical layer).

Then back in the PCB editor, you should select the primitives of this outline and invoke Design -> Board Shape in order to specify to the Altium software where the board edges are (this helps with Altium's Error checking, and eye candy).
[image]